# How to make a linear transformation in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello for an assignment i need to implement a histogram clipping on a double RGB picture.

So I have to parameters low and high which should be transformed to 0,1.
So basically what I want to do is a linear transformation like this:

```
[low, high] = [0,1]
```

After that all values `< 0` and `> 1` should be set to 0 and 1 respectively.

My problem is that I don't know how to make such a linear transformation in matlab, and didn't had any success googling it. I am new to Matlab, but I'm sure there should be an way to do this.

Comment: You need to more clearly state your question. I assume what you mean is this: 
I need to transform an image subject to two parameters: low and high. The transform should map the image's pixel values to in the range low:high to the range 0:1, and values less than low or greater than high are set to 0 and 1 respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: yeah i simply wanna stretch the interval [low, high] to [0,1]
Just a linear transformation f:[low,high] -> [0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set your parameters high and low:

```
low  = 0.2;
high = 0.8;
```

Perform the linear transformation:

```
image_new = (image_old - low) / (high - low);
```

Apply thresholding:

```
image_new(image_new > 1) = 1;
image_new(image_new < 0) = 0;
```